# Regex match alternates with optional part

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a regex to match either one option or another in the same group, in this example, group 1:

```
>>> x = re.match('(a)|b(c)', 'a')
>>> x.group(1)
'a' # Fine

>>> x = re.match('(a)|b(c)', 'bc')
>>> x.group(1)
'' # Not fine
```

Since only one group should match, I want the regex output to put them in the same group.

Is this possible?

Comment: Ah, okay.  I think I need to clarify the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookbehind assertion match alternate part in same group:

```
>>> print re.search('(a|(?<=b)c)', 'bc').group(1)
c
>>> print re.search('(a|(?<=b)c)', 'a').group(1)
a
```